# Android Upgrading MSAL 1.5.0 in existing project

Tags: android, kotlin, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am successfully able to open the login page. But when I am providing the correct login credentials, I am getting this in logcat.

`com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalClientException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $`

using below library for MSAL -

```
implementation ("com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:**1.5.5**") { exclude group: 'com.microsoft.device.display' }
```

Comment: Please include the code you have in your project that is working with the MSAL, and what you have tried to get this working, the more relevant information you provide, the easier it is for the community to be able to help you. You can edit your post to include this information in code blocks.

Comment: @Ralex,Please reply to above comment if you are still looking for help?